# JSON loop and add sum to variable

Tags: javascript, json, api, for-loop

I've been working with the GitHub API and trying to pull in the languages split per each repo. I've had two main issues:

1. Accessing the full list outside of a 'for loop'
2. Adding the loop output to create a sum total

Here's what i've gotten so far:

```js
function repoLanguage(repoName, divId) {
  var repo = repoName;
  var div = divId;

  function languages() {
    var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    for(x in responseObj) {
      var lang = x;
      var percent = Math.round(responseObj[x]/33256*1000) /10;
      var results = lang + "(" + percent + "%), ";
      document.getElementById(div).innerHTML += results;
    }
    // Cut string of trailing comma and add period.
    var str = document.getElementById(div).innerHTML;
    var cutStr = str.slice(0, -2) + ".";
    document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = cutStr;
  }
  // JSON http Request
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onload = languages;
  request.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/DubDJ/'+repo+'/languages', true);
  request.send();
};

repoLanguage('chat-with-alex', 'languages');
```

```html
<div id="languages"></div>
```

Basically, i'd like to replace the static total number with a variable total, but i'm having trouble adding all the values of the JSON file.

```js
for(x in responseObj) {
      var lang = x;
      var total = responseObj[x];
      var percent = Math.round(responseObj[x]/total*1000) /10;
      var results = lang + "(" + percent + "%), ";
      document.getElementById(div).innerHTML += results;
    }
```

I've tried moving the total outside of the language function but it only returns the last value every time. I've tried`total += responseObj[x]` and `total = responseObj[x]++` and a lot of other ways but I can't get the solution. I've googled and search with no luck. Hopefully somebody more knowledgable can advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the object once to calculate the total before the percentages:

```
var total = 0;
for (var lang in responseObj)
    if(responseObj.hasOwnProperty(lang))
        total += responseObj[lang];
console.log(total);
```

Comment: This solved the issue, still a little confused by some aspects of why certain things function the way they do in JavaScript, thanks for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could calculate the total number of lines in a separate loop before.

```js
function repoLanguage(repoName, divId) {
  var repo = repoName;
  var div = document.getElementById(divId);

  function languages() {
      var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log('initial resoponse is', responseObj);
      //first let's get total number of strings
      // by summing the lines from all languages
      var total = 0;
      for (x in responseObj) {
        if (!responseObj.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;
        total += responseObj[x];
      }
      //then use it
      for (x in responseObj) {
        var lang = x;
        var percent = Math.round(responseObj[x] / total * 1000) / 10;
        var results = lang + "(" + percent + "%), ";
        div.innerHTML += results;
      }
      // Cut string of trailing comma and add period.
      var str = div.innerHTML;
      var cutStr = str.slice(0, -2) + ".";
      div.innerHTML = cutStr;
    }
    // JSON http Request
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onload = languages;
  request.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/DubDJ/' + repo + '/languages', true);
  request.send();
};

repoLanguage('chat-with-alex', 'languages');
```

```html
<div id="languages"></div>
```

What you got from the github api, it a [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) response. With [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method you are converting it to an [Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp):

```
{ "HTML": 21934,
  "CSS": 6402,
  "JavaScript": 4412,
  "PHP": 508 }
```

[Keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)(property names) of this object are representing a language name and property values are representing number of lines written in the particular language (so there are 2193 lines of HTML in the project, 6402 of CSS etc). The total number of line for your percent calculation formula should be the sum of all languages' lines. To sum all the values you need an extra loop:

```
var total = 0;
for (x in responseObj) {
  if (!responseObj.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;
  total += responseObj[x];
}
```

If you try to sum in the same [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) (despite the language you use), you will get only value for HTML (21934) for first iteration then CSS (6402) etc. So you will get the whole amount only to the end on the whole loop.
To check this you can either [debug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger), or temporary use a [console.log(yourVariable)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) on a variable you are interested in to see how the things are changed for real during execution of your code.

With ES7 you will be able to use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead:

```js
    function repoLanguage(repoName, divId) {
      let repo = repoName;
      let div = document.getElementById(divId);

      function languages() {
          let responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          //first let's get total number of strings
          let total = Object.values(responseObj).reduce((acc, v) => acc += v, 0);
          //then use it
          Object.entries(responseObj).forEach(([lang, lines], i, o) => {
            let percent = (lines / total).toLocaleString("en", {
              maximumFractionDigits: 2,
              style: "percent"
            });
            div.innerHTML += `${lang}(${percent})${i < o.length? ', ': '.'}`;
          });
        }
        // JSON http Request
      let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onload = languages;
      request.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/DubDJ/' + repo + '/languages', true);
      request.send();
    };

    repoLanguage('chat-with-alex', 'languages');
```

```html
<div id="languages"></div>
```

Comment: I'm generally inexperienced with JavaScript but thanks for expanding with the extra info. Solved my issued.

Comment: I've tried to expand the answer and add some links to documentation. Good luck in learning JS! :)

Comment: That's great, thanks for the expanded answer.  I'll definitely plan on looking at ES7 in the future.